# sql server error = This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my code.

I use this code for create a view on sql server :

```
SELECT
(SELECT FirstNameD + ' ' + LastNameD AS Expr1
 FROM   dbo.UsersDatas) AS UsersFullName,
 PhoneNumberD, EmailAddressD, UserNameD
FROM dbo.UsersDatas AS UsersDatas_1
```

and use this view in my c# application.

after I set two rows with my c# app, I get this error from Visual Studio :

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error
>   occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the
>   inner exception for details.'

my c# code is:

```
private void SetDataGridViewDatasMethod()
{
    var Query = from MU in DataBaseDataD.VW_UsersDatasView
    select MU;
    var UsersDataD = Query.ToList();
    UsersInfoDataGridView.ItemsSource = UsersDataD;
}
```

and I search a lot about it on the internet but I can't find any solution could you help me fix this problem please?

Comment: If you just want to concat the names simply: `select FirstNameD + ' ' + LastNameD as UsersFullName, PhoneNumberD, ... from ...` - there is no need to a subquery.

Comment: I've had this error a few times. Make sure the subquery you select only returns one result if you compare it to another object. You test it by changing your subquery to only deliver one result "TOP(1)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want fullname you can do like this,
no need of inner query

```
 SELECT
FirstNameD + ' ' + LastNameD  AS UsersFullName,
 PhoneNumberD, EmailAddressD, UserNameD
FROM dbo.UsersDatas
```

Answer (score 0):

As Shantanu says - no need for the inner query.
And rather than using the "+" operator you might want to use CONCAT

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstNameD, ' ', LastNameD)  AS UsersFullName,
 PhoneNumberD, EmailAddressD, UserNameD
FROM dbo.UsersDatas
```

Or, if you're using SQL Server 2017 you could also use CONCAT_WS

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstNameD, LastNameD)  AS UsersFullName,
 PhoneNumberD, EmailAddressD, UserNameD
FROM dbo.UsersDatas
```

The key difference between + and CONCAT is how they behave when one of the inputs is NULL.